# Spin, directions and measurement

Tags: nuclear-physics, potential, quantum-spin

The question I'm trying to answer is: *does the spin of a particle have a fixed direction without measuring it?*

I understand that when I measure the spin of a particle using, say, a magnetic field, the spin can be parallel or antiparallel to the field, so it obviously has a direction (it's a vector quantity after all). But I'm not sure if I understand what Krane means in the book Nuclear Physics when saying

> The only reference direction for a nucleon is its spin, and thus only terms of the form $\vec{s} \cdot \vec{r} $ or $\vec{s} \wedge \vec{r} $, which relate $\vec{r} $ to the direction of $\vec{s} $, can contribute.

Does a single nucleon's spin have a fixed direction on its own? If I choose the $\vec{r} $ direction to be pointing, say, north, can I study the property of the nuclear interaction without measuring its spin (and thus choosing some physical quantization axis)?

I think that my perplexity arises from the fact that, while $\vec{B} $ is a physical quantity, $\vec{r} $ is just something one can choose. Does Krane mean that $\vec{r} $ is such that $\vec{B} =B\vec{r} $?